# Delay in Rails send_data() procedure

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, passenger

I have the following piece of code in my controller which generates a kml file:

```
def generate_kml

 links = Link.all.where('status = 1')

 links_hash = {}
 links.each do |link|
  if links_hash["#{link.siteid1}-#{link.siteid2}".to_sym]
    links_hash["#{link.siteid1}-#{link.siteid2}".to_sym][:count] += 1
    links_hash["#{link.siteid1}-#{link.siteid2}".to_sym][:links] << link
  else
    links_hash["#{link.siteid1}-#{link.siteid2}".to_sym] = {}
    links_hash["#{link.siteid1}-#{link.siteid2}".to_sym][:count] = 1
    links_hash["#{link.siteid1}-#{link.siteid2}".to_sym][:links] = [link]
  end
 end
 links.clear


 sites = {}
 links_hash.each_value do |linklist|

   siteid1 = linklist[:links].first.siteid1
   siteid2 = linklist[:links].first.siteid2
   longitude1 = linklist[:links].first.longitude1
   latitude1 = linklist[:links].first.latitude1
   longitude2 = linklist[:links].first.longitude2
   latitude2 = linklist[:links].first.latitude2


    kml_string << "\n\n<Folder>"
      kml_string << "\n<name> #{siteid1} - #{siteid2}</name>"

      if sites[siteid1] != true
        sites[siteid1] = true
        #place the first point
        kml_string << "\n<Placemark>\n<styleUrl>#site_icon</styleUrl>"
          kml_string << "\n  <name> #{siteid1}</name>"
          #kml_string << "\n  <description>#{site_properties link, 1}</description>"
          kml_string << "\n  <visibility>1</visibility>"
          kml_string << "\n  <Point>"
            kml_string << "\n    <coordinates>#{longitude1},#{latitude1}</coordinates>"
          kml_string << "\n  </Point>"
        kml_string << "\n</Placemark>"
      end
      if sites[siteid2] != true
        sites[siteid2] = true
        #place the second point
        kml_string << "\n<Placemark>\n<styleUrl>#site_icon</styleUrl>"
          kml_string << "\n  <name> #{siteid2}</name>"
          #kml_string << "\n  <description>#{site_properties link, 2}</description>"
          kml_string << "\n  <visibility>1</visibility>"
          kml_string << "\n  <Point>"
            kml_string << "\n    <coordinates>#{longitude2},#{latitude2}</coordinates>"
          kml_string << "\n  </Point>"
        kml_string << "\n</Placemark>"
      end



      points = generate_points(latitude1, longitude1, latitude2, longitude2, linklist[:links].size)

      line_count=0
      linklist[:links].each do |link|
         #draw a line
         kml_string << "\n<Placemark>"
            kml_string << "\n  <name> #{siteid1} - #{siteid2}</name>"
              kml_string << "\n  <description>#{link_properties link}</description>"
              kml_string << "<styleUrl> #working_link_line#{line_count+1}</styleUrl>"
              kml_string << "\n  <LineString>"
                 kml_string << "\n    <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>"
                    kml_string << "\n    <coordinates>#{points[line_count][0]},#{points[line_count][1]} #{points[line_count+1][0]},#{points[line_count+1][1]},0</coordinates>"
              kml_string << "\n  </LineString>"
         kml_string << "\n</Placemark>"

         line_count += 1
      end


     kml_string << "\n</Folder>"  
  end  


  links_hash.clear


  send_data kml_string, 
        :type => 'charset=utf-8; text/xml', 
        :disposition => "attachment; filename=kmlfile.kml"
end
```

The size of the file is 2.87 MB.

The problem: when I invoke the *generate_kml* procedure by clicking a link to this action in the controller, nothing happens. I can't see any progress in the status bar, or any indication that file download has been started. After 10 seconds, the file is downloaded instantly. This is what happens when I run my application locally on my Mac.

But when I deploy this application on one of our (powerful) local servers (on a LAN with Ubuntu Server + Nginx + Phusion Passenger), the delay takes even more longer time (about 60 seconds) before the same kml (of the same size) is downloaded instantly.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on and possible workaround?

Comment: We of course can't know the cause of the delay because you've chosen to omit that code from your Question. That said, good practice is not to require a user wait for long-running tasks to complete. Such tasks should be queued through something like [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque). In your case I might be inclined to email the user the KML file once generated.

Comment: I added the the source code, but I don't think that the cause of the delay is code itself. I run it locally on my Mac on the same database and it works blazingly fast.

Comment: By the way, I removed send_data from the source code and tried to run. It took no more than 5 seconds to complete the whole generate_kml action. So, it is definitely send_data that takes so much time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I solved the problem. Just want to share in case someone encounters the similar problem.

The bottleneck was our proxy. I just added the IP address of the Rails application server (where my application resides) to the list of exceptions (bypass-proxy list) from my browser, and it worked like a charm, it took 5 seconds to generate and download the file.